# Moving away from localstorage, saving txt to server, Ajax and PHP (*Working example*)

Tags: javascript, php

In my way to move from Super-Noob to Semi-Noob, I'd like to stop using localStorage and start saving data to my little server at Hostgator.

I managed to make this work but I not sure If I did it the right way.

Basically my intent here is the following:

- Have independent .txt files for each city.
- Make http request, load and display .txt content.
- Edit content by the user.
- Make http POST request to Save new content to same .txt file.

and here is my problem, in order to save to same .txt, I had to make a buch of "if", "else if". I don't believe this is the right way to accomplish this goal.

The code is working fine, but what is the right way? or if you have any suggestion please feel free to share!  Thank you! :)

**============--->>>**
[WorkingExampleHERE](http://qualitytraining4less.com/CITY/city.html)

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <header id="choose">
        <button id="LA">Los Angeles</button>
        <button id="Chicago">Chicago</button>
        <button id="NY">New York</button><br>        
    </header>
    <div id="result">

        <p id="comment">choose your city</p>
        <input type="text" id="addComment">
       <button id="saveBTN">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

javaScript:

```
let loadMytext, saveMyText2PHP,MyLoadedTXTItems
document.getElementById('choose').addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(event.target.id =='LA'){
   loadMytext = 'LosAngeles.txt'
   saveMyText2PHP = 'LosAngeles='
}else if(event.target.id =='Chicago'){
   loadMytext = 'Chicago.txt'
   saveMyText2PHP = 'Chicago='
}else if(event.target.id =='NY'){
   loadMytext = 'Ny.txt'
   saveMyText2PHP = 'Ny='}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr.open('GET', loadMytext, true);
  
xhr.onload = function(){        
    if(this.status==200){                        
        console.log(this.responseText)
        MyLoadedTXTItems = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
        document.getElementById('comment').innerHTML = MyLoadedTXTItems[0].text
        document.getElementById('addComment').value = MyLoadedTXTItems[0].myValue
    }}

    xhr.send()

});

document.getElementById('saveBTN').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let myValue = document.getElementById('addComment').value
    
    var entry = {
    "text": MyLoadedTXTItems[0].text,
    "myValue": myValue
    }
    MyLoadedTXTItems[0] = entry
    
var data = saveMyText2PHP+JSON.stringify(MyLoadedTXTItems);  
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
  
  setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true) }, 1000);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","save.php",true);        
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(data);        
})
```

php:

```
<?php

if($_POST['LosAngeles']){
   $post_data = $_POST['LosAngeles'];
   $file = 'LosAngeles';
}else if($_POST['Chicago']){
   $post_data = $_POST['Chicago'];
   $file = 'Chicago';
}else if($_POST['Ny']){
   $post_data = $_POST['Ny'];
   $file = 'Ny';
}

if (!empty($post_data)) {     
  $filename = $file.'.txt';
  $handle = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $post_data);
fclose($handle);    
}
?>
```

You see, soooo many crazies IFs!!!  :O

Comment: Nothing has been sent to the Server. You have `xhr.send()` inside of `xhr.onload = function(){}`. `xhr.send()` needs come after `xhr.onload = function(){}`, and it should send your `FormData` instance. Also, note that `xhr.onload` fires when `xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4`, so there's no need for that test.

Comment: but how can that be, @StackSlave - this is a *working example* :p

Comment: Nothing has been sent to the Server???
No, the code is working, the problem is the IFs!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what a round trip using the `XMLHttpRequest` would look like. Feel free to reuse my Library. I used it for the example. You can pay attention to the code after `// magic below except end load`:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, responseType = 'json', context = null)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  x.send();
  return x;
}
post = function(url, send, success, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, x.response);
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      let s;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        fd.append(k, s);
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = function(node, className){
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
// magic below except end load
const city = I('city'), ops = city.options, out = I('output');
city.onchange = ()=>{
  post('response.php', {city:ops[ops.selectedIndex].text}, resp=>{
    if(resp.city){
      out.textContent = resp.city;
    }
    else{
      // roundtrip failure - hacker
    }
  });
}
}); // end load
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.main{
  background:#ccc; overflow-y:auto; padding:10px;
}
label{
  margin-right:4px;
}
select{
  border:0; border-radius:3px; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <label for='city'>City</label><select id='city'>
      <option>Seattle</option>
      <option>San Francisco</option>
      <option>New York</option>
      <option>Boston</option>
      <option>Chicago</option>
      <option>Philadelphia</option>
      <option>San Antonio</option>
    </select>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since the above code sends to `response.php` that could look like:

```
<?php /* response.php */
$o = new StdClass;
if(isset($_POST['city'])){
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  if($city === 'Seattle' || $city === 'San Francisco' || $city === 'New York' || $city === 'Boston' || $city === 'Chicago' || $city === 'Philadelphia'){
    $o->city = $city;
  }
  else{
    // hacker
  }
}
echo json_encode($o);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me check this out!! :)